Using Composite and Visitor pattern to render a OpenGL scenegraph
I'm trying to implement a Open GL (4.6) setup with the Composite pattern (for a scene graph with Node, Cube and TransformNode classes) and the Visitor pattern (with a DrawVisitor to handle rendenring). The scene will draw multiple cubes, and I want to be able to do transformations on them (scale, rotation, translation) with TransformNodes.
I have some sort of base implemented that doesn't work still, but I can't wrap my head around how all of this works together. Here's a visual of how I see it at the moment


When drawing the nodes, how should the DrawVisitor combine the transformations from the TransformNode? In the current design, a node only has access to its parent. I'm not sure how to properly apply all parent transformations to a child node, especially since the DrawVisitor is visiting nodes independently. How can I ensure that each Cube gets the correct transformation matrix when rendered, and how to use the mesh properly?

Possible duplicate of Using Composite and Visitor pattern to render a OpenGL scene graph

This pattern moves you in the opposite direction from modern rendering, i.e. reducing number of draw calls via instancing/multi-draw-indirect, etc. I would suggest you to think about the systems as if you have 1 renderer, which knows about the whole group of similar objects at once, and renders them all to the same target (FBO) in 1 draw call

@AlexeyS.Larionov is the order of rendering supposed to start from the lowest node in the hierarchy, like recursive? Or does it start directly from the root?

Note: you appear to be trying to re-invent what was previously available as Open Inventor.  That being the case you might want to take a look at a current implementation such as Coin3D.
